# Deep Learning with TensorFlow on Compute Engine VM

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, google-compute-engine

I'm actualy new in Machine Learning, but this theme is vary interesting for me, so Im using TensorFlow to classify some images from MNIST datasets...I run this code on Compute Engine(VM) at Google Cloud, because my computer is to weak for this. And the code actualy run well, but the problam is that when I each time enter to my VM and run the same code I need to wait while my model is training on CNN, and after I can make some tests or experiment with my data to plot or import some external images to impruve my accuracy etc.

Is There is some way to save my result of trainin model just once, some where, that when I will decide for example to enter to the same VM tomorrow...and dont wait anymore while my model is training. Is that possible to do this ?

Or there is maybe some another way to do something similar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a trained model in TensorFlow and then use it later by loading it; that way you only have to train your model once, and use it as many times as you want. To do that, you can follow the [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#overview_of_saving_and_restoring_models) regarding that topic, where you can find information on how to save and load the model. In short, you will have to use the *SavedModelBuilder* class to define the type and location of your saved model, and then add the *MetaGraphs* and variables you want to save. Loading the saved model for posterior usage is even easier, as you will only have to run a command pointing to the location of the file in which the model was exported.

On the other hand, I would strongly recommend you to change your working environment in such a way that it can be more profitable for you. In Google Cloud you have the [Cloud ML Engine](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/) service, which might be good for the type of work you are developing. It allows you to train your models and perform predictions without the need of an instance running all the required software. I happen to have worked a little bit with TensorFlow recently, and at first I was also working with a virtualized instance, but after following some tutorials I was able to save some money by migrating my work to ML Engine, as you are only [charged for the usage](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/pricing). If you are using your VM only with that purpose, take a look at it.

You can of course consult all the available documentation, but as a first quickstart, if you are interested in ML Engine, I recommend you to have a look at [how to train your models](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/training-steps) and [how to get your predictions](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/online-predict).

Comment: Man thank you a lot for so clear explanation. Now I will try to migrate to Cloud ML Engine. Thanks for google that gives me credit of 300$ as a trail period...so it's not about my money, for now. 
Thanks for good advice, you help me a lot !